# how to convert timeseries ranking table to individual rank table in pandas dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

for example, ranktable is

```
time/rank  1  2  3
   1       a  b  c
   2       b  c  a
```

and I want convert this to individual rank by time

```
time/individual a  b  c
    1           1  2  3
    2           3  1  2
```

with pandas dataframe, code is below..

```
ranktable = pd.DataFrame([{
    'time': 1,
    1: 'a',
    2: 'b',
    3: 'c'
},{
    'time': 2,
    1: 'b',
    2: 'c',
    3: 'a'
}])

resultIWant = pd.DataFrame([{
    'time': 1,
    'a': 1,
    'b': 2,
    'c': 3
}, {
    'time': 2,
    'a': 3,
    'b': 1,
    'c': 2
}])
```

is there any easy way to convert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df = (ranktable.melt('time')
               .pivot('time','value','variable')
               .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
               .reset_index())
print (df)
   time  a  b  c
0     1  1  2  3
1     2  3  1  2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `pandas.DataFrame.apply`:

```
new_df = ranktable.set_index("time").apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.index, index=x), 1)
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
      a  b  c
time         
1     1  2  3
2     3  1  2
```